# I need to redirect http to https connection with nginx on rest service and need to test it on postman or soapui

Tags: nginx, centos, https, http

here is my nginx.conf file:
What should i change to make it work and how to get certificate

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
     server {
    listen       80;

    server_name hostname_of_virtual_machine http://ipaddress:port;


    return 301 https://$ipaddress:port$request_uri;
}


# Settings for a TLS enabled server.

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  hostname_of_virtual_machine;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        #ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
        #ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
        #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        #ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        #ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
        #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you need to remove the configuration codes after `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`

> Note: The example below using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

2. Go to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and create a new file `myapp01` and put your configuration there.

> `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available`

> `sudo vi myapp01`

Refer below snippet:

```
upstream appname-server {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name appname.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/appname-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/appname-error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://appname-server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 5m;
        proxy_send_timeout 5m;
}


    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/your/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/ssl/cert_key.pem;
}


server {
    if ($host = appname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    server_name appname.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404;
}
```

3. Don't for get to add `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in `nginx.conf`. (Thanks to [Drifter104](https://serverfault.com/users/278665/drifter104) for notifying)

   ```
    http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
   ```
4. Next, go to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and create symbolic links for `myapp01`, refer instructions below.

> Go to sites-enabled
> `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

> Create symbolic links for myapp01
> `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp01 .`

4. After that, test your nginx configuration using `sudo nginx -t`. If everything is successful, proceed to step 5.
5. Reload nginx `sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Hope it helps you, cheers.

Comment: If you are going to suggest this you need also add `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` to the nginx.conf otherwise nginx won't read the files in `sites-enabled`

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thank you for adding that